# Eloquent eager load custom query

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Category model that uses Baum. And each category has active_products field that has number of active products in that category. What I need is that I can get number of active_products not only for category but for all its descendants aswell.

Currently I have this in place:

```
$active_products = Category::select('active_products')
                ->where('lft', '>=', $category->lft)
                ->where('lft', '<=', $category->rgt)
                ->where('enabled', 1)
                ->lists('active_products');
```

And I return array_sum of $active_products.

But sometimes is use it inside foreach and its can produce lots of queries. I can't figure out how to solve this. Can I eager load a custom query instead of relationship?

EDIT #1: I actually don't need a relationship. I just need every category to have something like active_products_count attribute or something which value is sum of `active_products` field from category itself and its descendants. And I'd like it to behave like this:

`Category::where('somecondition)->with('active_products_count);`

So when I loop through the categories I don't need to make additional queries? Any ideas how this can be done? (Don't actually have to use "with" and eager-loading but this was the closest thing I could come up with)

Comment: There are two approaches to this. 1) Either use the Eloquent way, where you mention the relationship in the Model itself and Eager load the relationship by using the `with` function. 2) Use `DB::raw` to create the raw query if you are using a custom query. Both are possible in your case.

Comment: Can you please post your `Category` model as well?

Comment: No, you can't do that with eloquent relationships. Rather use custom query to get all the data you need, let these queries run or use collection methods - depending on the number of categories you have.

Comment: for the eager loading to work correctly u should call the relations first then the `where` , ex.`Category::with('user','products','etc...')->where('somecondition)->get();`